# how to deny access to user but enable to php script from .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, file, .htaccess

I have a server which stores images in a folder called 'images' but I want it to only be accessed by the php scripts.
Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `images` folder, create an htaccess file with:

```
Deny from All
```

Then in your php scripts, you do something like:

```
<?php
$file = 'images/image.jpg';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you block direct access with a simple .htaccess

```
deny from all
```

You can use [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to read the image from the filesystem and output the bytes to the HTTP response body.